# Конфликт с драйверами видеокарты в XP, как переназначить прерывания для видеокарты?

Tags: видеодрайвера, видеокарта, windows-xp

После установки видовс XP ставлю драйвера для видеокарты ATI, после чего XP перестает загружаться, показывается статус бар экрана загрузки, через пару секунд на этом виснет. В безопасном режиме загружается нормально. В свойствах адаптера следующие ошибки:

[image]

Cписок конфликтующих устройств:

```
Диапазон ввода/вывода 03B0 - 03BB уже используется:
Intel(R) 82865G/PE/P/GV/82848P Processor to AGP Controller - 2571
Диапазон ввода/вывода 03C0 - 03DF уже используется:
Intel(R) 82865G/PE/P/GV/82848P Processor to AGP Controller - 2571
Диапазон памяти 000A0000 - 000BFFFF уже используется:
Intel(R) 82865G/PE/P/GV/82848P Processor to AGP Controller - 2571
```

Comment: @mr_blond97, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, прерывания обслуживаются BIOS, и их нельзя так просто поменять, если только через обатную разработку разобрать BIOS изменить код, скомпилировать обратно, уничтножить чип, вставить новый с нашим новым BIOS.

А если серьезно, Вам надо не прерывания копать, а тут, видимо, дело в том, что на материнке стоит встроенная видеокарта, которую, по идее, можно в  BIOS выключить - и все зарботает. Скачайте мануал по своему BIOS и найдите, как это там делается.

Как вариант, может быть дело и в драйвере, можно попробовать разные версии драйверов наиболее стабильные.

Comment: Ilja, Вы видимо не в курсе, но иногда эти настройки можно изменить и в винде. Я еще этим в 95-ой развлекался - там с прерываниями было намного тяжелее, чем сейчас (чаще встречались конфликты).  
И уже не все прерывания обслуживаются в БИОСе. Следует найти настройку Init_Display_First и установить в режим PEG (инициализация сначала PCI Express). Так же: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/bfc8789a-c21a-4f2a-adc0-53f1132413d6/-irq-pnp-windows-xp-pro-sp2?forum=xpru   и еще:  http://htpc.al.ru/html/niaia_irq.html

Comment: @Justicet, да я как-то почти ничего для оборудования не писал, баловался с написанием полу-драйвера для клавиатуры, убивал Винду 100 раз на дню, поэтому и опасаюсь изменения прерываний. Я просто даже никогда не слышал о том, что бывают такие конфликты и их так можно устранить, ну если можно, то автору поста удачи! :)

Comment: @Justicet, спасибо, кстати, за ссылки и короткий рассказ про прерывания, интересно.

Comment: @Ilja да не за что.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить эти настройки у контроллера Intel.

Comment: да. приходилось, но к счастью не на современных ОС - они почему-то эти проблемы сами решают. Здесь действительно есть всего два варианта решения: 1) или мы используем оба видеоадаптера; 2) или отключаем Интеловский нафиг, как менее мощный (предполагаю) - исходя из тех ссылок что привел выше, второй вариант предпочтительнее. Я не понимаю почему ТС изначально не отключил встроенный видеоадаптер

Comment: @Justicet, да и где сам автор, решил он или как?... :)

Comment: спасибо, статьи были познавательны, нет я не смог применить это на практике, во-первых в материнке нет встроеной видеокарты, во-вторых пункта Init_Display_First в биосе тоже нет) и вот эти пункты в биосе не понятны, как с ними вообще работать, там 4 строки, жмешь ентер на строке и выпадает список irq, но все дело в том, что в правом окне devices using this INT висят уже несколько девайсов, т.е. я не могу сами девайсы переназначать, а только IRQ строки на которой они разполагаются, какой в этом смысл?))http://www.manualslib.com/manual/271313/Gigabyte-Ga-8ipe1000.html?page=41#manual

Comment: и апофеозом стало то, что виндовс сразу после загрузки выпадает в синий экран, не важно обычный запуск или безопасный режим, уже несколько раз переставлял его и пробовал подключать другие видеокарты. Иногда при загрузке биос подает бесконечный непрерывный звуковой сигнал.

Comment: Попробуйте еще [это](http://remontcompa.ru/356-kak-otklyuchit-vstroennuyu-videokartu.html)  и напишите какая у Вас мать. А тот раздел куда Вы залезли - не тот. Похоже видео на проце